# C using while loop with linked list

Tags: c, list, while-loop, linked-list

I have come to a problem where I try to use while loop on linked list.
I have two linked lists, namely `temp` and `graph`. I am using a while loop to do tasks `while(temp != NULL)`. To move on in each of the loop, I am assigning `temp = temp->link`. However, this code does not compile. I realize that recursive function could be a solution, but the function is actually way more complicated that I don't think recursive would be such a good idea. By the way, `graph` is already a built linked list. Thanks in advance!

P.S. It is part of homework.

```
temp = graph->link;
while(temp!=NULL){
    if(stack->link == NULL){
        stack->link = (node_pointer)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        stack->link->weight = temp->weight;
        stack->link->vertex = temp->vertex;
    }
    temp = temp->link; //Here is the problem.
}
```

edit:

stack and graph are both arrays of linked list:

```
typedef struct node *node_pointer;

struct node{
    int vertex;
    int weight;
    int visited;
    struct node *link;
};
node_pointer graph[50];
node_pointer stack[50];
node_pointer temp;
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Could you at least show us the definition of temp, stack and graph. And it would help if you add the compiler error.

Comment: `However, this code does not compile. ` I don't understand this statement. You don't have any sintatic problem.

Comment: `Unhandled exception at 0x00d716c2 in graph.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd9.`

Comment: @meany This isn't a compiler problem. The code compiles very well

Comment: I wonder how you compile it without the header file

Comment: So you have uninitialized list (or the link).

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 to compile C. Does problem exist here perhaps?

Comment: You do not have a compiler error, you get a Access violation which indicates that you're trying to access memory which is not allocated. Check your linked-list, especially if temp->link is set to NULL at the end of the list.

Comment: I have created graph[]. However, I am currently building the stack in the function. The temp is just there to help the loop through graph.

Comment: btw. change the malloc() to malloc(sizeof (struct node))

Comment: Explicitly make `link` as NULL when creating the node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0xC00000005 is not a compile time error. This error usually happens when you access a memory location that you're not allowed to, even if its pointing to `NULL`. Its a runtime error. Check to see if `temp` is not NULL and is also `malloc`ed properly. Is it? Also check all other variables. Use a debugger, run it through `valgrind`. It will help you learn the language and debugging techniques properly. Especially CompileTime and RuntimeErrors ;-).

Also explicitly make `link` as `NULL` when creating a new node. Pointer variables usually contain a JUNK value without initialization. I am assuming you're not setting `link` to `NULL` and accessing a JUNK memory location. Garbage in Garbage out. Your logic of `IF TEMP(WHICH IS SET TO LINK) IS NOT EQUAL TO NULL` fails if LINK is *not null* but *is* junk.

Comment: No up votes, no discussions, no comments. Yet a selected answer. BEST DAY OF MY LIFE :-P - Thanks @meany

Comment: I did have to make link as NULL for the initialization haha Thank you for the advice!