# 0xC00000005 Uninstantiated pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on a singly linked list class in C++ for the sake of getting a better understanding of the language, and I've hit a wall.

The title is, sadly, pretty much all I can seem to figure out with the error. Both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821072/2351738) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/74320/) seem to suggest some answers that I've tried to no avail to implement.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList<string> moo2;
    moo2.insertAtFront("one");
    moo2.insertAtFront("two");
    moo2.insertAtFront("three");
    moo2.insertAtFront("four");
    cout<<moo2.toString() << endl;

    cin.ignore(1);
    return 0;
}
```

LinkedList.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <class type>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    int size;
    node<type> *head; 

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        //head = (node<type>*)malloc(sizeof(node<type>));
        size = 0;
    }
    /*LinkedList(const LinkedList<type> &x)
    {
        head = NULL;
        //head = (node<U>*)malloc(sizeof(node<U>));
        size = 0;
    }*/

    bool insertAtFront(type obj)
    {
        node<type> *temp;
        temp = (node<type>*)malloc(sizeof(node<type>));
        temp->data = obj;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;

        size++;
        return true;
    }

    std::string toString()
    {
        std::stringstream value;
        node<type> *i = head;
        while(i != NULL)
        {
            value << i->data;
            if(i->next != NULL)
                value << ", ";
            i = i->next;
        }
        return value.str();
    }
};
```

node.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

template <class type>
struct node
{
    type data;
    node *next;

    node() 
    {
        data = NULL;
        next = NULL;
        //data = new type();
        //next = (node<U>*)malloc(sizeof(node<U>));
    }
    node(type)
    {
        data = type;
        next = NULL;
        //next = (node<U>*)malloc(sizeof(node<U>));
    }
    node(type, node *)
    {
        data = type;
        next = next2;
    }
    /*node(const node &x)
    {
        data = new type(x->data);
        next = new x->next;
    }*/
};
```

I have no idea (with any certainty, anyway) which variable is creating the error, as it could be LinkedList's *head (or head->data or head->next) or it could be nodes *next.

What is truly strange though, is that for any other parameterized type that I've tried thus far (int, double, long, char, char*) the code works perfectly fine. In fact I could even use char* to essentially achieve the same goal as a string list. Still, I'd like to know why I'm having the issues and any steps that can be taken to fix it.

Comment: Start by replacing `malloc` with `new` (and almost never using either again after this).

Comment: I wish I could uptick chris' comment a thousand times. You do realize *none* of your `node` constructors (and thus their member initializations) are firing, right?

Comment: Also, this is broken: main24.cpp: In constructor ‘node<type>::node(type)’:
main24.cpp:19:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
         data = type;

Comment: Especially mixing new malloc as you commented it away, is a bound to go wrong when you are delete en freeing the data, since you can't combine malloc with delete and new with free. Once you did that you really want to work on destructors, since you allocate a lot.

Comment: @chris After some experimentation I got it working for all data types I've tested. However, out of curiosity, why do you say to almost never use either again? Is there a better way of accomplishing the same goal?

Comment: @headlessgargoyle, Use things like smart pointers and vectors instead of managing the memory yourself. If there's nothing available that's suitable (which doesn't happen very often), build your own small RAII class for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `new` instead of `malloc`.

`malloc` just allocates memory for a given type or size and it will not call constructors.